# Functions of AppDelegate not being called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscenedelegate

I have a problem with one of my apps. I noticed, that my Controller is still updating while the app is in the background. The reason for this is that the methods of the AppDelegate are not being called and I can not find out why.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Harmony

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate : UIResponder
{
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
        Swift.print("applicationDidBecomeActive")
        Notifications.post(UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification.rawValue)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
        Swift.print("applicationWillResignActive")
        Notifications.post(UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification.rawValue)
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
        Swift.print("applicationWillEnterForeground")
        Notifications.post(UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification.rawValue)
    }
}
```

I tried the following:

- Use real device and simulator.
- Restart Xcode, clean build folder.
- Clean Developer folder
- Do not use the extension.
- Debug or Release scheme

Nothing had an effect, the methods are still not being called and I am wondering why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ios 13 with scene delegate .. all functions are shifted in scene delegate instead of AppDelegate

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

Comment: So how can I call didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken inside of SceneDelegate?